# How to order data.frame in my specific 'vector' order in R language?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame showed below:

[image]

In order to analyse the relationship between those 10 features and disorder propensity, I need to sort the data.frame in my amino acids order which is stored in an vector like this `c("L", "I", "V", "Y", "C", "F", "R", "W", "M", "H", "N", "T", "G", "D", "Q", "A", "K", "S", "P", "E")`

I tried this `properties[aa == c("L", "I", "V", "Y", "C", "F", "R", "W", "M", "H", "N", "T", "G", "D", "Q", "A", "K", "S", "P", "E"), ]` which doesn't seem to work for me.

What's the right way to sort the data.frame in my 'vector' order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your column `aa` a factor and give the factor levels in the correct order. The factor can then be sorted according to the levels. Look at this example:

```
my_order <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B")  # defines the order

test <- c("A", "B", "Y", "Z", "Z", "A", "X", "X", "B")  # a normal character vector

test2 <- factor(test, levels = my_order)  # convert it to factor and specify the levels

test2  # original order unchanged

test2[order(test2)]  # ordered by custom order
```

Note that you must specify all occuring factor levels or this will not work!